# Setting a percentage value to border-width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to chop a triangle off the bottom of a `div` by using the CSS `border` "hack". (Creating a 0 width and height object and giving it a big ol' border and making one side of the border transparent and the other sides a solid color).

My problem is that the `div` in question has a percentage width. Consequently my border needs to have a percentage width as well (and possible height which is another potential problem as the `div` doesn't have a specified height). But, the css `border-width` property doesn't seem to support percentage values.

Alternative solutions to the problem of "chopping" a triangle off the bottom of a responsive `div` would also be okay.

Before someone recommends using an image or appending one I can't because the whole thing has a pattern and it wouldn't match up. Also I don't want to use multiple background images due to compatibility.

Comment: Hi there, could we possibly see some code?

Comment: http://tigatest.co.uk/cushion sorry about the mess! It's that cart thing in the top right, I'm trying to get it to look like this: http://imgur.com/Mtp9u

Comment: Please provide some code or clarify what you're trying to do. A screenshot or an image of what you would want it to look like would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using only CSS is not possible. for a hack of this class you can use the window resize event.

```
$w = $(window);
$w.resize(onResize);

function onResize(){

    $("div").css({
        "border-bottom-width": $w.width()*0.12,
        "border-left-width": $w.width()*0.1,
        "border-right-width": $w.width()*0.1
    });

}
onResize();​
```

with your css

```
div{
    border-color:blue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-top:0px;
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vuZaw/

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is looking to do this in future I tweaked Scipions answer a bit so it resizes based on the parent width not the window width (which makes more sense):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $o = jQuery(".topCart");
    $w = $(window);
    $w.resize(onResize);

function onResize(){

    $(".bottomBorder").css({
        "border-top-width": $o.width()*0.2,
        "border-left-width": $o.width()*0.52,
        "border-right-width": $o.width()*0.5
    });

}
onResize();
});
```

and it works great. This is really cool I think so hopefully someone else will find it useful too.